# Q. AWS lambda - Share database connection pool between lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a question about AWS lambda, and the best practice when it does database connection.

I want to write some lambda functions each which will handle CRUD operations.
So for function A it will do CRUD for one data model, and function B will do CRUD for another data model.

Now my question is, can the two lambda functions share the connection pool to a database?
I know that it is possible to reuse connection pool within a lambda when it is in a warm state.
Or would my option here to disconnect database when the request is finished?

Comment: Each Lambda instance runs in an entirely isolated environment for all intents and purposes. Yes, a warm instance can hold an open connection, but there's no way for it to share it with any other instance. You'd need something like a database proxy/load balancer between Lambda and your database to keep some pool of open connections; which requires constants infrastructure though, somewhat contrary to the idea of "serverless".

Comment: @deceze what's the best practice here then? I see two options, one is where I perhaps disconnect the database when lambda is done. Or let the database connection go away by itself when lambda goes back into cold state.
The second option is that I make one lambda function which does CRUD for every data model I'm going to have. Not sure which one is the better option though.

Comment: If you are using Amazon RDS you can use the AWS Lambda RDS Proxy feature, which should effectively do what you want. See [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-rds-proxy-with-aws-lambda/) and [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-database.html).

Comment: @starcorn -  You should close the connection on Shutdown life cycle event. We use Lambda as  background micro programs, and we have different lambda functions to do the different work, built with SRP in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Two important points have already been mentioned by [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65422256/q-aws-lambda-share-database-connection-pool-between-lambda-functions#comment115663813_65422256) and [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65422256/q-aws-lambda-share-database-connection-pool-between-lambda-functions#comment115669591_65422256) in the comments, I'm going to summarize some of the options you have and add my own take.

Each instance of a Lambda function (aka. execution context) is a **separate** Micro-VM based on AWS' firecracker framework, which means they can't share "process-level" information like active database connections among each other. The connection pool reuse you correctly referred to is therefore limited to a single execution-context, i.e. a warm Lambda instance.

Since opening up a connection to a database is a rather costly endeavor, AWS has some options to help you here. All of those that I'm aware of require you to use a RDS-managed database.

1. Use [RDS Proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/), which essentially acts as a reverse proxy in front of your database and "bundles" connections to it as well has does connection pooling. At the time of writing, this is available for the MySQL and Postgres versions of regular RDS as well as Aurora
2. Use the [Data-API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html) to talk to your Aurora Serverless Cluster. This allows you to connect to talk to your database using the HTTP(S) protocol and handles some of the underlying connection mechanisms. It's currently (late 2020) available for the Aurora Serverless versions of Postgres and MySQL - you can find [more details about availability here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.AuroraFeaturesRegionsDBEngines.grids.html#Concepts.Aurora_Fea_Regions_DB-eng.Feature.Data_API).

Answer (score 0):

Since 2019 you can use RDS Proxy. It is similar to a connection pool. It always to share connection for different AWS Lambdas. Another benefit is it caps your database connections to a certain limit. Your AWS Lambdas might scale faster than your database can handle. We use it in production an it works quite well. Small downsite, if you use RDS Proxy with Aurora and read replicas: your connections always talk to the writer.

Another practice we used quite successfully is having one connection per Lambda function open and reuse that one. Sure, you need to write your own logic to setup and verify a database connection, but it is not that hard to do.